# Refreshing DataTable from JSON object by calling $ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, datatable

I have a JSON object like that:

```
{
    "column1":
        ["a","b","c","d","e"],
    "column2":
        [1,2,3,4,5]
 }
```

And I'd like to refresh it on a DataTable by calling `$ajax` function. How it works?

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have so far

Comment: Please look up this tuturial on how to use Ajax with jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Please check this link http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.json()

Comment: I got JSON object:
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: JSONobject,
  type: "get",
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
   // getting json data
  },
  timeout: 12000,
  complete: setTimeout(example, 10000)
 });
</script>

and I was trying to build table using innerHTML, but I need to use DataTable instead...